Issue with Push Notification Logo on Motorola Devices (Ionic 6, Capacitor 5, Firebase)
I'm developing an app using Angular 17 with Ionic 6 and Capacitor 5. I'm encountering an issue with the logo in push notifications sent from Firebase. While the logo displays correctly on some devices, it does not appear on Motorola devices.
I've read that the logo should have a white background, but I don't fully understand why. For example, in WhatsApp notifications, the logo is the user's profile picture. I would like to understand how the logo should be designed to ensure it displays correctly across all devices, especially on Motorola. My specific questions are:
Should the logo have a specific size, shape, background color, or logo color?
Where should the logo images be placed within the project directories?
Is it necessary to include multiple versions of the logo for different resolutions?

Here is the relevant code where I implement the notification logo:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_icon" />
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
</manifest>

I tried making the logo a transparent letter in both black and white and in color, but it didn’t work. I also attempted using a round icon, but it still didn’t show up. I tried different sizes, but nothing seemed to resolve the issue. I'm hoping to find a solution to ensure the logo appears correctly on Motorola devices. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

SO is a question and answer site. Note that question is singular, not plural. The entire [se] network is designed around the concept of allowing one specific question per post, so that a single answer can be provided. If you have multiple questions, they belong in separate posts. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.
